# laravel POST request not rendering

Tags: laravel

Below is the auth part of my routes.

I just added the Tags part (where I can add another tag to the DB).

the tag creation works but the creation of a new post  doesn't work now (worked before).

When I "submit" a post, it doesn't redirect or submits anything and it refreshes me back to the post create form with empty fields like nothing was rendered.

I tried to play with the positions of the routing, I made the post creation work but than the same happened to the tag creation where the page was "submiting" but actually there was no submit and it didn't redirect afterwards.

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/posts', 'PostsController@index')->name('posts.index');

Route::middleware('can:isAdmin')->group(function () {

    Route::get('/posts/create', 'PostsController@create')->name('posts.create');

    Route::get('/posts/{post}/edit', 'PostsController@edit')->name('post.edit');

    Route::put('/posts/{post}', 'PostsController@update');

    Route::post('/posts', 'PostsController@store');


    Route::get('/tags/create', 'TagsController@create')->name('tags.create');

    Route::post('/posts', 'TagsController@store');
});

Route::get('/posts/{post}', 'PostsController@show')->name('posts.show');
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, in given configuration you have two routes for same method / URI combination, so one of them would be unreachable:

```php
    // here the first
    Route::post('/posts', 'PostsController@store');


    Route::get('/tags/create', 'TagsController@create')->name('tags.create');

    Route::post('/posts', 'TagsController@store'); // <-- here the second
```

Looks like your post form submit goes to the tags, than validation fails and it redirect you back to post create page. Do you display validation errors?

here is example - https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors

```
<!-- /resources/views/post/create.blade.php -->

<h1>Create Post</h1>

@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif

<!-- Create Post Form -->
```

Answer (score 0):

If it refresh your page so probably it works but if it do not save your request to databse it means that your request not validate respect to table.

Use `validation` for understand the errors.